# How is Schwarzschild metric asymptotically flat for large $r$?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, approximations

The Schwarzschild line element is:

$$ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)dt^2 + \left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2 +r^2(d\theta^2 +\sin^2\theta d\phi^2). $$

As $r \to \infty$, this is supposed to look like the Minkowski line element. I am unsure of how though. I know that the $(1-2M/r)$ terms look like 1, and $dr^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$. But as $r \to \infty$, $r^2$ blows up. How is this dealt with in this limit?

Comment: It reduces to the Minkowski metric is spherical coordinates.

Comment: Don't use $r\to\infty$, try $r>>2M$ if that helps you with the infinity issue.